# Compiler settings for show main func in IDA

Tags: ida, c++

Why in dissasemble code in IDA, some programs have func "main" in begin (in start window in IDA) like this:

```
cseg01:00038460 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
cseg01:00038460
cseg01:00038460 ; Attributes: noreturn
cseg01:00038460
cseg01:00038460 main_           proc near               ; CODE XREF: __CMain+40p
cseg01:00038460                 push    ecx
cseg01:00038461                 push    esi
cseg01:00038462                 push    ebp
cseg01:00038463                 mov     edx, 1
```

But some programs have func "start" in begin like this:

```
cseg01:00010124 ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
cseg01:00010124
cseg01:00010124
cseg01:00010124                 public start
cseg01:00010124 start           proc near
cseg01:00010124                 jmp     short loc_10186

;--------------------------

cseg01:00010186 loc_10186:                              ; CODE XREF: startj
cseg01:00010186                 sti
cseg01:00010187                 and     esp, 0FFFFFFFCh
cseg01:0001018A                 mov     ebx, esp
cseg01:0001018C                 mov     dword_20110, ebx
cseg01:00010192                 mov     dword_200FC, ebx
```

And in this second case func "main" located somewhere in code and named just not "main" mere with prefix sub_.

This probably depends on the C++ compiler (linker) settings, how to configure the C++ compiler (linker) always for "main" func show?

Comment: /link /entry:main  be aware no crt init will take place if you use this

Comment: I have same problem in WinAPI C++ project, in Visual Studio project settings I added Linker option -> Entry Point-> WinMain and in result of compilation I have many linker errors kind of - unresolved external symbol.